# Truble loading 'Hmisc'

Tags: r, package

I just downloaded the R package 'Hmisc' but when I try to open it I get this error:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Hmisc’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘jpeg’

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZknH.png)

Comment: Install the package jpeg. `install.packages('jpeg')`

Comment: You should learn to search on error code text before posting questions. This is a highly duplicated question.